# How would one integrate over $SO(n)$?

Tags: integration, group-theory, measure-theory, orthogonal-matrices, monte-carlo

Suppose you want to find the average of an $n\times n$ **diagonal** matrix $A$ over all possible rotations,
$$
\langle A\rangle = \int\limits_\text{SO($n$)} Q^T A Q \; dQ.
$$

It's easy enough to do this for $n=2$ because you have only one degree of freedom. I suspect that $n=3$ would be "simple", but tedious.

Using Monte-Carlo, I conjecture that $\langle A\rangle = \text{diag}\left[\text{tr}(A)/n \right]$. But I'm curious if there's a way that you could derive this relation analytically for a general $n$.

I suspect that you could make some symmetry arguments to take the problem of an integral over $\text{SO}(n)$ to a sum over permutation matrices.

---

Why take $A$ to be diagonal? Because really I'm interested in $A$ being positive-definite, and when that's the case, you can just diagonalize it and then rotate into the principal coordinate-frame.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> You might note that $\langle A\rangle$ is invariant under conjugation by an arbitrary rotation, concluding it's a scalar matrix; then take the trace of both sides to see you have the correct diagonal entry. If that checks out, please feel free to write up your own answer!

Comment: A small clarification: I presume you meant integration w.r.t. the Haar measure. In which case, as @AndrewD.Hwang pointed out, the answer simply follows from noting $B^T \langle A \rangle B = \langle A \rangle$ for any $B \in SO(n)$. The result is even true without assuming $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: $A$ need not be diagonal - this still holds. Just use an orthogonal change of variables.

Comment: Note: for dimension 2, every rotation commutes with all rotations, so in this case one can not conclude using the same argument that the matrix is a multiple of the identity.